# Subtracting an element of an array from another element of same array

Tags: ruby, arrays, subtraction

I have an array(`time`) containing float values. I want to do subtraction of the elements of this array and store the result in another array and further print it. I tried the following:

```
time=Array.new

time=open("/home/sakshi/Desktop/test/PACKET-WISE_DETAILS/pkt_time.tsv", &:read)

time.each do |i|
  puts time[i+1]-time[i]
end
```

but i am getting this error:

```
'in `+': can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError) ' error.
```

I also tried to rewrite the above code with a `while` loop but that is not working either.

Comment: whats in time? do `p time`. Also which version of ruby are you on?

Comment: time is my array in which I am taking lal the values from pkt_time file. But it is taking wrong values. Am I reading the file in a wrong way?

Comment: I am working with ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are adding integer value to object i.e. id, try this out

```
time = Array.new

time = open("/home/sakshi/Desktop/test/PACKET-WISE_DETAILS/pkt_time.tsv", &:read)

time.each_with_index do |i,index|

 puts time[index+1]-time[index] if index < time.size #to avoid overflow when reaches the end

end
```

Comment: It's still not working...It's giving me the following error:
pkt_time.rb:19: undefined method `-' for "2":String (NoMethodError)
 from pkt_time.rb:57:in `each_with_index'
 from pkt_time.rb:18:in `each'
 from pkt_time.rb:18:in `each_with_index'
 from pkt_time.rb:18

Comment: it is due to time[index+1] might contents string object object. try converting it in float using to_f. Also recheck by printing if it is valid number.